# How do I scrape this specific element from html?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color : #346fda;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="DOB - 23-10-1940">
                                        76 years old</a>
```

I'm trying to use Python 3.5 to scrape the "DOB - 23-10-1940" from the bit of html code above. When using:

```
//td/a[@href]/text()'
```

it only returns "76 years old"

I'm not sure how to call this in my script. Can someone help?

EDIT: for completeness the code I'm using to extract data from the html, which works fine for other elements:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    responses = requests.get(url)
    html_tree = html.fromstring(responses.content)
    d_o_b = html_tree.xpath('//a[contains(@data-original-title, "DOB - 23-10-1940")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//td/a[@href]/@data-original-title
```

It's a attribute, use `@` to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: html_tree.xpath('//td/a[@href]/@data-original-title', smart_strings=False) returns empty values so I'm not sure whether this fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[contains(@data-original-title,"DOB - 23-10-1940")]
```

I think there is a more aesthetic solution, but it should work so

UP:

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
g.go('https://www.futbin.com/17/player/50')

for elem in g.doc.select('//*[@id="info_content"]/table/tr'):
    print(elem.select('td').text())
```

result:

```
Iniesta
FC Barcelona
Spain
LaLiga Santander
4
4
Right
171cm | 5'7"
68
Normal
Med
High
2016-09-21
N\A
32 years old
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It doesn't, however, fix the problem. Still returns empty values. I'm starting to wonder whether that part of the html is even accessible at all with python's requests library

Comment: The thing is I need to access it on a 15000 different URLs, so referencing the literal value may work for one single instance of the script but will hit a wall as soon as the value in the html is "DOB - 04-10-1956" instead of DOB - 23-10-1940

Comment: You can describe in detail what you want to get from html

Comment: If possible, give an example of the donor of the page html and the data to be obtained from it

Comment: Thanks again for replying. An example website is this one: https://www.futbin.com/17/player/50. In the left side of the page there is a table which displays information of the specific player (name, club, nation, league etc.). At the bottom of the table there is the player's age displayed as a hyperlink. What I want to extract is the Date Of Birth information behind this hyperlink, which is what is shown in my first post. Unfortunately I'm running into a wall on how to access it.

Comment: I've also added some more code in my original post for completeness